# iOS - simulate keyboard animation on Notes application

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, keyboard

I went through lot of posts to change the position of the keyboard in iPhone programmatically. But, there seems to be no chance. But I noticed cello feature in my iPhone 5S with iOS 9.3.2 that, After typing something in a Note, when we do the scrolling from the top to bottom and the finger crosses over the top of the keyboard then the keyboard starts moving down as and when dragging the finger over the keyboard.

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway to do this kind of animation programmatically.

Comment: You mean to hide the keyboard programatically? Or to have it hide interactively on user scroll?

Comment: I meant to have hiding the keyboard as per the user scrolls downwards. Like the rate at which I scroll downwards, the keyboards moves downwards. Use Notes iPhone app or Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5IrRysWPlg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to achieve is a default behavior in iOS, though you need to tell the system that you want it. There is a property `keyboardDismissMode` on `UIScrollView` (so it is also available for its subclasses, like `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`).

You can set this either in code :

```
self.scrollingView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

Or in IB :

[image: IB screenshot of setting keyboard dismiss mode]